# Force the chrome web driver to load a Japanese language website translated into English

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The website link is:

https://used.sofmap.com/r/item?categories1%5B%5D=audio&stock_shop_code%5B%5D=298&stock_type%5B%5D=2&categories2%5B%5D=midi

I need this website to load translated into English.

This is what i have attempted:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--lang=es')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

I have also tried:

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

But nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `add_experimental_option` and `prefs`

```
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {'ja': 'en'}, # translate from Japanese to English
    "translate": {'enabled': 'true'}
}

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Notice it will translate the site *after* the url is loaded, it will not load it already translated. Loading the site already translated using `options.add_argument('--lang=en')` requires the site to support localization. The `prefs` option uses Google translate to to the translation after the site is loaded.,